# uglifyjs-folder remove console.log & alert from minified files

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, npm, uglifyjs-folder

I am minifying multiple files in a folder using `uglifyjs-folder` in `npm` `package.json` like :

```
"uglifyjs": "uglifyjs-folder js -eyo build/js"
```

It is working as intended & minify all files in folder.

I want to remove any **console.log** & **alert** while minify but not able to find any option with `uglifyjs-folder`https://www.npmjs.com/package/uglifyjs-folder

Please help.

Comment: As far as i researched, i see that : uglifyjs-folder does not have any option to remove console.log and alerts. It just scan the folder and send each file to uglify-js to minify. But uglify-js can do this , [see here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uglify-js).  Also uglifyjs-folder is not passing its options to uglify-js. So, ı suggest you to use [grunt](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt) to apply same uglify-js options to all folder

Comment: we have removed `gulp` from solution & not using `grunt`, we have `npm` & `webpack` for compiling `react` & `sass`.  `uglify-js` can not compile multiple files inside different folder hierarchy so using `uglifyjs-folder`

Answer (score 1):

#### Short Answer

Unfortunately, [uglifyjs-folder](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uglifyjs-folder) does not provide an option to silence the logs.

---

#### Solution

You could consider writing a nodejs utility script which utilizes [shelljs](https://github.com/shelljs/shelljs) to:

- Invoke the `uglifyjs-folder` command via the `shelljs` [`exec()`](https://github.com/shelljs/shelljs#execcommand--options--callback) method.
- Prevent logging to console by utilizing the `exec()` methods [`silent`](https://github.com/shelljs/shelljs#execcommand--options--callback) option.

The following steps further explain how this can be achieved:

1. **Install**

   Firstly, `cd` to your project directory and install/add [shelljs](https://github.com/shelljs/shelljs) by running:

```
    npm i -D shelljs
```

2. **node script**

   Create a nodejs utility script as follows. Lets name the file: `run-uglifyjs-silently.js`.

   ```js
   var path = require('path');
   var shell = require('shelljs');

   var uglifyjsPath = path.normalize('./node_modules/.bin/uglifyjs-folder');

   shell.exec(uglifyjsPath + ' js -eyo build/js', { silent: true });
   ```

   *Note: We execute `uglifyjs-folder` directly from the local `./node_modules/.bin/` directory and utilize [`path.normalize()`](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_normalize_path) for cross-platform purposes.*
3. **package.json**

   Configure the `uglifyjs` script inside `package.json` as follows:

   ```json
   {
     ...
     "scripts": {
       "uglifyjs": "node run-uglifyjs-silently"
       ...
     },
     ...
   }
   ```
4. **Running**

   Run the script as per normal via the command line. For example:

   ```
   npm run uglifyjs
   ```

   Or, for less logging to the console, add the `npm run` [--silent](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/run-script) or shorthand equivalent [-s](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/run-script) option/flag. For example:

   ```
   npm run uglifyjs -s
   ```

---

#### Notes:

- The example gist above assumes that `run-uglifyjs-silently.js` is saved at the top-level of your project directory, (i.e. Where `package.json` resides).
- ***Tip:*** You could always store `run-uglifyjs-silently.js` in a hidden directory named `.scripts` at the top level of your project directory. In which case you'll need to redefine your script in `package.json` as follows:

  ```json
  {
    ...
    "scripts": {
      "uglifyjs": "node .scripts/run-uglifyjs-silently"
      ...
    },
    ...
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

`uglify-folder` (in 2021, now?) supports passing in terser configs like so:

`$ uglify-folder --config-file uglifyjs.config.json ...other options...`

and with `uglifyjs.config.json`:

```
{
  "compress": {
    "drop_console": true
  }
}
```

And all options available here from the [API reference](https://terser.org/docs/api-reference#compress-options).